# Adding tikz figure in caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I am writing one long document using lyx. I wanted to add small tikz code within a caption of a figure of my document. However when I tried to run it it is giving following error. Please help me resolve this problem.

```
! Use of \use@pgfplotslibrary doesn't match its definition.
\pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a {
                                               #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@...
l.1411 ... method \label{fig:Velocity-curves-for}}
```

Here is the code portion

```
 \documentclass{svmono}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
 \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{esint}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
 \fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
 \DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{%
 \IfFileExists{grtm10.tfm}{}{\fontfamily{cmr}}\greektext #1}}
 \DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
 \DeclareTextSymbol{\~}{LGR}{126}
 \newcommand{\lyxmathsym}[1]{\ifmmode\begingroup\def\b@ld{bold}
 \text{\ifx\math@version\b@ld\bfseries\fi#1}\endgroup\else#1\fi}

 %% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
 \providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
  \usepackage {tikz,pgfplots}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,snakes}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

  \@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
   \usepackage{subfig}
   \makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\centering{}\caption{Velocity curves of the vehicle for 1$^{st}$ scenario. (a) DWA.       \tikz[baseline]\draw[dashed,thick, color = blue](0ex,0ex)--(1ex,0ex);(b)
The proposed method \label{fig:Velocity-curves-for}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same question and its answers on the LaTeX community forum: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=23280

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to "protect" the TikZ picture if you are going to use it in section headings or figure captions.

Change

```
\tikz[baseline]\draw[dashed,thick, color = blue](0ex,0ex)--(1ex,0ex);
```

to

```
\protect\tikz[baseline]\protect\draw[dashed,thick, color = blue](0ex,0ex)--(1ex,0ex);
```

For more information, see the **[TeX FAQ entry on protection](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-protect)**.