# Checkmark with specific color

Tags: symbols

I am trying to include a checkmark in my table that has for example blue color.
I have managed to do it using a solution i have found here by using:
`\def\bluecheck{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4, color=blue](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}`

end then calling `\bluecheck`

The problem is when i insert `\bluecheck` in the caption of my table i get a number of errors (even though it compiles and renders the expected pdf)

Is there a library that creates a checkmark that allows to set its color?

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116661/adding-tikz-figure-in-caption

Comment: Look at [several options here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132785/59109).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem is that `\bluecheck` is not a robust command and breaks inside moving arguments like `\caption`. The caption title moves via the `.aux` file to the `.lot` file for the list of contents. The solution is to define the command with `\DeclareRobustCommand` or with `\protected\def`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\bluecheck}{}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bluecheck}{%
  \tikz\fill[scale=0.4, color=blue]
  (0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;%
}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{table}
\caption{Blue check mark \bluecheck}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 14):

Ti*k*Z is overkill here. Just use a symbol and colour it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pifont}
\newcommand*\colourcheck[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1check\endcsname{\textcolor{#1}{\ding{52}}}%
}
\colourcheck{blue}
\colourcheck{green}
\colourcheck{red}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{OK \greencheck}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \bluecheck & \greencheck & \redcheck\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: coloured checks]

`pifont` provides an alternative check if you don't like this one, or use one from the font of your choice, otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

Or, since you're probably using `amsmath` anyway.....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\bluecheck}{{\color{blue}\checkmark}}

\begin{document}
\bluecheck
\end{document}
```