# Using tikzpicture within section title

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, symbols

I used tikz to define some custom symbols. They work fine in the text, but I have problems using them in a section title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\customSymbol}[1]
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
This works fine: \customSymbol{}.
% \section{This does not work: \customSymbol{}}
\end{document}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The sectioning content is written to an external file, so it can not include "fragile" macros. Try `\section{This should work: \protect\customSymbol{}}` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding tikz figure in caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116661/adding-tikz-figure-in-caption). Please see the explanation and link in the accepted answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 \DeclareRobustCommand\customSymbol[1]{...}
```

Comment: I think you are missing curly braces around the command name (i.e. use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\customSymbol}[1]{...}` instead). For other newbies like me, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61503/newcommand-vs-declarerobustcommand) general discussion of robust vs. new command might also be helpful