# Using tikzpicture as robust command within section title

Tags: tikz-pic, robust-commands, section-titles

I was trying to use a tikzpicture using a robust custom command in a section title as is it described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406881/using-tikzpicture-within-section-title/524355#524355). I'm not getting error when using the robust command but my custom symbols definition is printed after the correct symbol and section title. In a normal text everything works perfectly fine, tough. The command for the picture I got from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328886/making-a-directory-tree-of-folders-and-files/328987#328987).

```
\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\DeclareRobustCommand\customFile{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]{
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
}
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

When I use the custom command in a section the definition of the folder symbol is printed after the section:

```
\subsubsection{\customFolder{} bubbleInterTrackFoam}
```

[image]

Any suggestions what may this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If you REALLY want to make it robust (and faster), use a savebox.

Answer (score 1):

**Adaptations:**

- created MWE
- removed parameter `#1` from definition
- use defined `\customFile` instead of undefined `\customFolder`

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\DeclareRobustCommand\customFile{
    \begin{tikzpicture}{
        \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \section{\customFile bubbleInterTrackFoam}
    \subsection{\customFile bubbleInterTrackFoam}
    \subsubsection{\customFile bubbleInterTrackFoam}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hey dexteritas, thanks for your help and the quick reply. I see now that the error happens due to the custom document class I'm using to write my thesis. I am using [this] (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl) template, which reproduces the error when I use your code. :(

Comment: If you want further comments on your problem you should make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) as I suggested above. You can edit your question for this.