# Tikz in caption leads to error even with \protect

Tags: tikz-pgf, undefined

According to [Adding tikz figure in caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116661/adding-tikz-figure-in-caption) it suffices to add protect to make my program compile.
Indeed, it compiles after adding the command, but TeX still throws an error message that the control sequence is undefined.

What portion of the command definition of `\circled` leads to the problem?

```
\documentclass[twoside,runningheads, oribibl, draft]{llncs}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
    \protect\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[shape=circle, draw, inner sep=1.5pt, font=\small] (char) {#1};
}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        Hello World
        \caption{Derivation of premise \circled{2}}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: make the \circled command robust: `\NewDocumentCommand\circled{m}{...}`

Comment: You need to put `\caption{... \protect\circled{2}}`. Putting `\protect` inside `\circled` is too late.